# Sending email with multiple pdf attachments

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, attachment

I am trying to send multiple pdf files (different amount each time).

I have code, which works in different spreadsheets with attaching one file, but doesn't work on this one even though the pdf is created using name from the same cell as the attachment.

I have a list of all the files to attach (without pdf extension) in the column "a" starting with row 14 and need to attach 1-10 files until the cell is empty.

The code for one attachment that works elsewhere:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        
    ' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        
    ' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName1 As String
    
    Path = "C:\Users\File Folder\"
    FileName1 = Range("A14")
    
    PathFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileName1 & ".pdf"
    
    With objEmail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "company@company.com"
        .To = "company@company.com"
        .Subject = FileName1
        .Body = "Have a nice day!"
    
        .Attachments.Add PathFileName
        .Display        ' Display the message in Outlook.
    End With
        
    ' CLEAR.
    Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing
            
ErrHandler:
    '
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Const FLDR = "C:\Users\File Folder\" 'files are here
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object, cFile As Range
    Dim fPath As String
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'edit: fixed position
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    Set cFile = ActiveSheet.Range("A14") 'cell with first file name
    
    With objEmail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "company@company.com"
        .To = "company@company.com"
        .Subject = "Attached file(s)"
        .Body = "Have a nice day!"

        'check each file, and add if found
        Do While Len(cFile.Value) > 0
            fPath = FLDR & cFile.Value & ".pdf"
            If Len(Dir(fPath)) > 0 Then   'check if file exists
                .Attachments.Add fPath
            Else
                MsgBox "File not found" & vbLf & fPath, vbExclamation
            End If
            Set cFile = cFile.Offset(1) 'next file
        Loop
        .Display        ' Display the message in Outlook.
    End With
    
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work, no error messages, just nothing.

Comment: No output in the Immediate window in the VB editor (Ctrl+G to open)?  Did it create an email?

Comment: It didn't create an email, in my previous code also, unless I commented out the attachment. Immediate widow message shows: Object variable or With block variable not set
Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Comment out the line `On Error GoTo ErrHandler`  - what happens when you run the code?  If you get an error what is it, and on which line?

Comment: It says Runtime Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: Sorry I'd swapped the line `Set objOutlook = ...` to the wrong position - see fix above

Comment: Now the error message is: Run-time error '424': Object required and in the immediate: Object required
Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: As noted above, if you comment out the `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` you can see which line has the problem (click "Debug" when the error window pops up).  You must disable the error handler to do this.

Comment: Sorry about this, the error is on line fPath = FLDR & c.Value & ".pdf". Is it possible that because names start with date it creates a problem? Format is the same, in the name of the pdf and the list of attachments

Comment: Ok, it vorked, I changed c.Value to cFile.Value. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes my bad, sorry about that.  I accepted your edit.